# Logging HikariCP Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, logging, properties, datasource, hikaricp

i set my properties in my application.yml

```
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout: 30000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size: 10
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout: 600000
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle: 10
```

Spring is 2.1.9.RELEASE

How can i log these parameter to check that the application has taken the configurations correctly?

Thank's

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24448947/how-to-log-the-active-configuration-in-a-spring-boot-application

Comment: I need see the value into hikari class, not to environment of springboot

Comment: logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig=DEBUG
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari=TRACE

Comment: I noticed that with Spring Boot 2.7.0, you need to drop the `hikari.` part in the properties names probably because Hikari is the default `DataSource` implementation.  Also add
  `logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig=DEBUG ` and 
 `logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari=TRACE`
if you want to verify that your properties where correctly registered.

Comment: It is correct, as mentioned by @PierreC, that with Spring Boot 2.7.0, you need to remove Hikari, as it will not work. Instead, you should use the properties `spring.datasource.minimumIdle` and `spring.datasource.maximum-pool-size`. 
It's interesting to note that IntelliJ didn't show a warning for these properties when Hikari was present, but without Hikari, it shows a "Cannot resolve config property" error.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

If you have springboot and you want logging your HikariCP parameters to check that the application has taken the configurations correctly put this in your application.yaml or application.properties

```
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig=DEBUG 
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari=TRACE
```

Console will show you all

Comment: Pool status gets printed every 30seconds. Is there any parameter we can use to specify this time?

Comment: @KavyaJain When you look in the `com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool` class you'll find a housekeeper task that runs every 30s and does the logging. It seems to be undocumented and it would affect more than just logging, but you can change how often it runs with the system property `com.zaxxer.hikari.housekeeping.periodMs`, e.g. `-Dcom.zaxxer.hikari.housekeeping.periodMs=10000` to run every 10s.

Comment: The information logged can be wrong due to this spring framework bug: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/29607