# How to view properties of running spring boot application from command line

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kubernetes

I have an application deployed to k8s (linux). The application is not working as expected. I want to verify that the properties created using Application.yml are correct.

Application.yml looks like this

```
foo:
  bar: ${FOO_BAR}
  baz: ${FOO_BAZ}
```

When I shell into the pod and run `env | grep FOO` I see that the values of `FOO_BAR` and `FOO_BAZ` are what I expect. I want to verify that in the Spring Boot application foo.bar and foo.baz are also correct.

Is there a command I can run from the command line that will print out the values of foo.bar and foo.baz?

I've tried:

`jinfo <pid>` - Does not output the values I am looking for

`jps` and `jps -v` - No output

Comment: If your application is able to run (even with these properties broken), you could enable the `/actuator/env` actuator ([documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html)). Otherwise see if this question answers yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48212761/how-to-log-all-active-properties-of-a-spring-boot-application-before-the-beans-i

Answer (score 0):

you can run shell command on a running pod as shown below

```
kubectl -n namespace exec -it pod-name -- /bin/bash -c "command(s)"
```