# How to list all properties of a project at start time?

Tags: spring-boot

How do I log all properties on a spring-boot application at start time?

Something like Spring (framework, not boot):

Best i could find was something that will log properties AFTER spring boot:

```
<logger name="org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver" level="TRACE" />
```

This will mostly work, but not to debug issues with a spring boot autoconfigurer, which all load before the framework. For example, if my hikariCP datasource have a crash, i can't see in the logs which properties values I had.

Comment: maybe this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303381/how-to-log-properties-loaded-by-spring can be helpful ?

Comment: Thanks @George I've updated the question to be more clean that this is about spring boot. That Q/A are about spring framework, and it have one more complex requirement than just logging things statically at start.